# Is it possible to run an android app as root

Tags: android, root

I know it's possible to run **commands** as root with `Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su -c ps");`

But what about using `File()` to read on `/data/user/0/......` is it possible? Maybe with Magisk?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside a JVM there is no `root` user, therefore it is impossible. This might explain it better:
https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/133466/how-does-supersu-provide-root-privilege

And I barely use the term "impossible", but in this case only the underlying Linux OS may provide a root shell - also C/C++ native assembly could escalate privileges, as it is running on the actual OS. `Runtime.getRuntime().exec()` also just executes in a shell (which is not a part of the JVM).